# AutoFailover with the MySQL

Tags: mysql

Using mysql 8 on windows 10
MySql replication master-slave using GTID based(binlog-format = mixed;)        . mysqlreplicate ,mysqlrplcheck,mysqlrplshow,mysqlrpladmin commands are ok but mysqlfailover command got 
ERROR: Query failed. 1694 (HY000): Cannot modify @@session.sql_log_bin inside a transaction.

How do you fix this problem?

Comment: First, please explain _why_ you need to do such.

Comment: MySql replication master slave using GTID based. binlog-format = mixed;    
Using mysql 8 on windows 10. mysqlreplicate ,mysqlrplcheck,mysqlrplshow,mysqlrpladmin commands are ok but mysqlfailover command got error. ERROR: Query failed. 1694 (HY000): Cannot modify @@session.sql_log_bin inside a transaction.

Comment: Sounds like a bug to report at bugs.mysql.com